# Gradient of a scalar with respect to a row vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

How is the gradient of a scalar wrt column vector different from the gradient of a scalar wrt to a row vector?

Is gradient of a scalar wrt a column vector is a column/row vector?

Comment: [Gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) is not taken with respect to any vector, did you mean [directional derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative)?

Comment: A scalar is just a number. Do you mean scalar field?

Answer (score 1):

The gradient of a scalar valued function with respect to a vector may be defined in multiple ways, it depends on the [layout convetion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions) you follow:

Numerator layout:

$$\frac {\partial y}{\partial \mathbf {x} } = \begin{bmatrix}{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{1}}}&{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{2}}}&\cdots &{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{n}}}\end{bmatrix}$$

Denominator layout:

$$
\frac {\partial y}{\partial \mathbf {x}} = \begin{bmatrix}{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{1}}}\\{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{2}}}\\\vdots \\{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{n}}}\\\end{bmatrix}
$$

Or mixed layout:

$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \mathbf{x}'} = \begin{bmatrix}{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{1}}}&{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{2}}}&\cdots &{\frac {\partial y}{\partial x_{n}}}\end{bmatrix}$$